# Errors on building Tensorflow on Intel Atom

Tags: linux, tensorflow, intel, bazel

I build Tensorflow on Intel Atom. Bazel is 0.15. The console command to build is

```
bazel build --config=mkl --cxxopt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --copt=-march=atom --copt=-mtune=atom //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I have

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

Two errors are

```
ERROR: /home/upsquared/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:533:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tf_python_api_gen_v1 failed (Exit 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: /home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

The whole error messages are

```
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-self-assign'
ERROR: /home/upsquared/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:533:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tf_python_api_gen_v1 failed (Exit 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/upsquared/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/upsquared/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools.api.generator import doc_srcs
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/upsquared/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/upsquared/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/upsquared/.cache/bazel/_bazel_upsquared/64ad7d1d27724ec626c14ec5fee17883/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_1.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 7602.740s, Critical Path: 240.17s
INFO: 5845 processes: 5845 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: It looks like either (1) GCC 5.4 cannot handle `-Wno-self-assign`; or (2) the warning is being passed directly to the preprocessor via `CPPFLAGS` instead of the compiler through `CFLAGS`. In either case just delete the warning option. `grep -IR '\-Wno-self-assign'` will help you find it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure it is because of bazel version, so now I changed to 0.18 and build again. I'll test your suggestion also.

Comment: Not very sure what I did solved the issue. I changed to bazel0.18. `keras_preprocessing` and `keras_applications` import errors still came out after that and solved by installing in pip. Finally Tensorflow is installed successfully.

Comment: What branch of tensorflow are you building ? In the later versions (r1.13 for example), the bazel WORKSPACE clearly specifies: `check_bazel_version_at_least("0.18.0")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installation instructions:

1. Ensure numpy, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, pip, six,
   wheel, mock packages are installed in the Python environment where
   TensorFlow is being built and installed.
2. Clone the TensorFlow source code and checkout 1.12 branch

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
   git checkout r1.12
   ```
3. Run "./configure" from the TensorFlow source directory
4. Execute the following commands to create a pip package that can be used to install the optimized TensorFlow build.

   PATH can be changed to point to a specific version of GCC compiler:

   ```
     export PATH=/PATH//bin:$PATH
   ```

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH can also be to new:

   ```
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/PATH//lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

   Set the compiler flags support by the GCC on your machine  to build TensorFlow with Intel® Math Kernel Library (Intel® MKL). Ensure appropriate "march" and "mtune" flags are set.

   ```
     bazel build --config=mkl --cxxopt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --copt=-march=sandybridge --copt=-mtune=ivybridge --copt=-O3 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
   ```

   (or)

   Alternatively, set appropriate "Instruction sets" flags you want to compile the library with:

> Flags set in the command below will add AVX, AVX2 and AVX512 instructions which will result in "illegal instruction" errors when you use older CPUs. If you want to build on older CPUs, set the instruction flags accordingly

```
       bazel build --config=mkl -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mavx512f --copt=-mavx512pf --copt=-mavx512cd --copt=-mavx512er //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

5. Install the optimized TensorFlow wheel

   ```
   bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package ~/path_to_save_wheel

   pip install --upgrade --user ~/path_to_save_wheel/<wheel_name.whl>
   ```

For reference, please go through this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide

Comment: Atom supports up to SSE4.2, but not AVX.  If `bazel` and/or Tensorflow's build scripts worked properly, you could just use `-march=native` to compile for the current CPU, but `--copt=-march=native` doesn't Just Work for some reason, last I heard.